# Basis of the integer ring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$

Tags: number-theory, extension-field, integer-rings

I am solving an exercise with the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)/\mathbb{Q}$

I am suck trying to prove that:$$B = \{a+b(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}) |a,b\in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ 
Where B is the integer ring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$.

The deffinition I have of integer ring is: the subset of elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ whose irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}$ has integer coefficients.

I have showed that $B \supset \{a+b(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}) |a,b\in \mathbb{Z} \}$, but I cannot  fully prove the equality

I have read that $\{ 1, \dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\}$ is a basis of B, but I haven't found a proof.

If someone could porvide a proof, give me a hint or point me to some source material I would be very thankful.

Comment: Take $a + b\sqrt 5$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Q$. What is its minimal polynomial? Make that polynomial monic, then if it is in the ring of integers, the $x$ and constant coefficients have to be integral, which gives you two constrains on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @HwChu , I was hopping for a more elegant argument, but I did it that way and it worked. I will addit the question to add my solution when I have the time. Thank you!